# React passing variables between js files

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started building a website with react, I want to have a js file where I can have all the text and images src in one place for easier access and editing, i am able to pass text variables eaisly using export and import but i am struggling with passing images src,

As you can see in this example:

Banner.js:

```
<Img src={this.props.src} />
<h3>{this.props.text}</h3>
```

Index.js:

```
import {bannerSrc, bannerText} from './assets/js/vars.js'
//Render!
<Banner
    src= {bannerSrc}
    text= {bannerText}
    />
```

vars.js:

```
module.exports = {
    bannerSrc: "./assets/imgs/banner.jpg",
    bannerText: "Some text to appear in banner!"
}
```

In my Vars.js files, I want to have all my text and image sources, Banner.js is my component I want to pass the variables to using props, And index.js is where I want to import all my variables from vars.js

The text is rendering okay, but the image is not working!

Comment: Are you accounting for the fact that the relative path will be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not importing or requiring the image. You have two options here.

**First One**

Change export in `var.js`.

```
module.exports = {
    bannerSrc: require( "./assets/imgs/banner.jpg" ),
    bannerText: "Some text to appear in banner!"
}
```

**Second One**

Use `require` like this in `Banner`:

```
<img src={require( "" + props.src )} />
<h3>{props.text}</h3>
```

Do not omit `"" +` part, if you do `require` can not use your variable.